# Error when trying to add user input to an array

Tags: java

I am quite new to java and am having a problem trying to store user input to an array to later be able to call the list, however I am getting an error when trying to do so. The error comes on the newvoter.add(); line. Sorry if I'm being ignorant in any way, I feel like I'm being stupid!

```
public class admin {

public static Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
public static List<voter> Voters = new ArrayList<voter>();


        public static int promptUserInput() {
            System.out.print("\n\tEnter: ");
            int option = sc.nextInt();
            return option;
        }
        public static int getOption() {

            int option = promptUserInput();

            switch(option){
            case 1:
                addVoter();
                break;
            case 2:
                //deleteVoter();
                break;
            case 3:
                Questions openQuestions = new Questions();
                openQuestions.addQuestion();
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Programme Ended");
                System.exit(0);
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return option;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            printMenu();
        }

        public static void printMenu(){
            System.out.println("\nAdmin Options Menu\n"
                    + "\t\nPlease enter an option:\t\n"
                    + "\n\t\t1: Create Voter\t\n"
                    + "\t\t2:Delete Voter\t\n"
                    + "\t\t3:Add Questions\t\n"
                    + "\t\t4: View Questions List\t\n"
                    + "\t\t5: Delete Question\t\n");

            getOption();
        }


        private static void addVoter(){

            voterAdd newvoter = new voterAdd(); // Creates a new voter

            System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
            String firstName = sc.next();

            System.out.println("Enter Surname Name: ");
            String surname = sc.next();

            System.out.println("Enter Voter ID: ");
            int voterID = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter City: ");
            String city = sc.next();


            newvoter.setVoter(firstName, surname, voterID, city);//calls the 'setVoter' method inherited from 'voter'

            newvoter.add();//adds the 'newVoter' to the ArrayList 'voter'

            System.out.println("\n New voter identification has been created and stored.\n");
            listVoters();
        }
```

Here is the class it calls from..

```
public class voterAdd {

private String firstName = "";
private String surname = "";
private int voterID = 0;    //voterID of the voter
private String city = "";

public void setVoter(String firstName, String surname, int voterID, String city) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.voterID = voterID;
    this.city = city;   
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;

}
public String getsurname()
{
    return surname;
}

public int getID()
{
    return voterID;
}
public String getCity()
{
    return city;
 }

}
```

Comment: You are mixing constructor and regular methods, why are you declaring methods static, you have "voterAdd newvoter = new voterAdd(); // Creates a new voter"  you can not instantiate methods please check :          http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/84/getting-started-with-java-language#t=201612032331046355282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `Voters.add(newvoter);`, not `newvoter.add()`. Also, variable names should start with a lowercase letter or an underscore. Classes should start with uppercases.

Answer (score 0):

Well one of your problems is that you are calling in your List the voter class, when maybe it should be the voteradd class like such:

```
List<voteradd> listName = new List<voteradd>();
```

Another thing, common java principles expect java classes to start with a capital letter(camel case), it's just good conventions and good practice. Hopefully this helped, best of luck :)